# Blank page during twitter authentication

Tags: android, twitter, twitter4j

I use tutorial from http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-post-twitter-status-from-android/comment-page-2/#comment-10881.

I change:

```
mHttpOauthprovider = new DefaultOAuthProvider(
      "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token",          
      "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize",          
      "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token");
```

and `CALLBACK_URL` but I am getting blank page in autorization:

http://imageshack.us/f/834/device20111201110552.png/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the comments of the tut, there is a fix for the blank authorization page.  4th comment above yours. Give that fix a shot.

Comment: It help but now it's not return to app. And I get a page from callback:
http://imageshack.us/f/638/device20111201133338.png/
The callback url should has no effect on mobile app, it only works for web app.